# Filling space between two functions in matplotlib: unsightly patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm looking to fill the space between two predefined functions, i.e.:

```
def stravinska_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    strav_SII = 1.2 + eps + 0.61 / (log_SII_Ha - eps + 0.2)
    strav_SII[log_SII_Ha > eps + 0.05] = -2
    return strav_SII
```

and

```
def log_OIII_Hb_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    return 1.30 + eps + 0.72 / (log_SII_Ha - eps - 0.32)
```

However, after moving the `np.linspace` to give the function appropriate boundaries (as it shoots off towards y = +∞) I now have a patch which remains unfilled. I was wondering if i could ask the community ways of filling the empty patch with a novel new method...?

Here is a picture of what I will refer to as the patch problem:

[image]

N.B. I'm hoping I could define some function, i.e., a horizontal line at y = 1.5 between -0.2 < x < 0.06 that I could then use to fill (as the axhline is quite problematic as it uses a scaling relation...)

A self contained plot of my problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

SII   = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.20)
SIIs  = np.linspace(-3.0,-0.38)

def log_OIII_Hb_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    return 1.30 + eps + 0.72 / (log_SII_Ha - eps - 0.32)

def stravinska_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    strav_SII = 1.2 + eps + 0.61 / (log_SII_Ha - eps + 0.2)
    strav_SII[log_SII_Ha > eps + 0.05] = -2
    return strav_SII

fig = plt.figure()
gs_left   = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs_left[0,0])

ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII), '-k')
ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII, 0.1), '--k')
ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII, -0.1), '--k')
ax.plot(SIIs, stravinska_SII(SIIs), '-.k')
ax.set_xlim(-2.0, 1.0)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 2.5)

ax.fill_between(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII), stravinska_SII(SII),      where=log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII)>=stravinska_SII(SII),
             facecolor='gray', alpha=0.45, edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you boil this down to a simple, self-contained example that reproduces the problem and includes your plotting code? are you using `ax.fill_between?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fill_between` works nicely as long as you have nicely behaving continuous (in respect to X) data. If you don't then you might consider some other methods.

One possibility would be to create a polygon by hand. The polygon would have the following edges:

- points on the first limiting curve
- points on the second limiting curve

The nice thing is that with this approach you do not have any x/y constraints, and you may even use parametric curves if you want.

Applied to your simple example:

```
# create the limiting polygon
vert_x = np.concatenate((SII, SIIs[::-1]))
vert_y = np.concatenate((log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII), stravinska_SII(SIIs[::-1]))) 

p = plt.Polygon(np.column_stack((vert_x, vert_y)), facecolor='gray', alpha=.45, edgecolor='none')

ax.add_artist(p)
```

With this your example becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`stravinska_SII` has an asymptote at x=-0.2.  Matplotlib is appropriately trying to fill *above* the line for x>-0.2.  You are using the `fill_between` `where=` parameter to hide this fill.

You need to either change your function `stravinska_SII` to not produce large positive numbers above x=-0.2 or accept the fact that filling above the line is appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't take in any data, just a simple np.linspace(xmim,xmas) setup.

Comment: So what do I apply the np.clip() to exactly? My data is not used to create the lines, it is the defined functions...the np.linspace is then used to plot those lines for a given range, i.e. np.linspace(-2,2)

Comment: I have added how the lines are plotted to the above question. Hopefully you can see that the function, if it is not clipped to the xrange (-3.0,-0.38) will shoot off in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

SII   = np.linspace(-3.0, 0.20)
SIIs  = np.linspace(-3.0,-0.38)
Y2    = np.linspace(-0.2575, 0.06)

def log_OIII_Hb_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    return 1.30 + eps + 0.72 / (log_SII_Ha - eps - 0.32)

def stravinska_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
    strav_SII = 1.2 + eps + 0.61 / (log_SII_Ha - eps + 0.2)
    strav_SII[log_SII_Ha > eps + 0.05] = -2
    return strav_SII

def y(x):
    y = (x**2) - 1.682687002
    return y

fig = plt.figure()
gs_left = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs_left[0,0])

ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII), '-k')
ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII, 0.1), '--k')
ax.plot(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII, -0.1), '--k')
ax.plot(SIIs, stravinska_SII(SIIs), '-.k')
ax.plot(Y2, y(Y2), ':k')
ax.set_xlim(-2.0, 1.0)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 2.5)

ax.fill_between(SII, log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII), stravinska_SII(SII),    where=log_OIII_Hb_SII(SII)>=stravinska_SII(SII),
             facecolor='gray', alpha=0.45, edgecolor='none')

ax.fill_between(Y2, y(Y2), log_OIII_Hb_SII(Y2),
             facecolor='gray', alpha=0.45, edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```